# How to restore SQL Server .bak in Amazon RDS

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Trying to restore a .bak file from S3.

I have tried on SQL server express and web. Versions 2012 through 2017.

I have tried with t2.micro and t2.small.

Here is what my `task_info` says:

```
 [2018-03-21 10:20:22.107] Task execution has started.
 [2018-03-21 10:20:22.280] myDb.bak: Completed processing 17.27% of S3 chunks.
 [2018-03-21 10:20:22.327] myDb.bak: Completed processing 34.48% of S3 chunks.
 [2018-03-21 10:20:22.357] 9 percent processed.
 [2018-03-21 10:20:22.373] myDb.bak: Completed processing 51.68% of S3 chunks.
 [2018-03-21 10:20:22.450] myDb.bak: Completed processing 68.88% of S3 chunks.
 [2018-03-21 10:20:22.500] 13 percent processed.
 [2018-03-21 10:20:22.513] myDb.bak: Completed processing 86.09% of S3 chunks.
 [2018-03-21 10:20:22.547] 18 percent processed.
 [2018-03-21 10:20:22.560] myDb.bak: Completed processing 100% of S3 chunks.
 [2018-03-21 10:20:22.640] 23 percent processed.
 [2018-03-21 10:20:22.653] Read on "F470E52D-DEA8-4EB1-B0AC-6F03D091E223" failed: 30(The system cannot read from the specified device.)
 [2018-03-21 10:20:22.653] RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
 [2018-03-21 10:22:22.027] myDb.bak: S3 processing completed successfully
 [2018-03-21 10:22:22.027] Aborted the task because of a task failure or a concurrent RESTORE_DB request.
 [2018-03-21 10:22:22.090] myDb.bak: S3 processing has been aborted
 [2018-03-21 10:22:22.107] Unable to retrieve family guid for database name: myDbName
```

I have searched all over the web and no luck.

the process is outlined here: 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/SQLServer.Procedural.Importing.html

Any help would be great!

UPDATE

I noticed on this page: 
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/migrating-microsoft-sql-server-enterprise-workloads-to-amazon-rds-part-1/

it says:

> You might see this error when the database you have restored contains
>   a large log file and SQL Server is performing crash recovery. Shrink
>   the log file on premises before creating a backup, uploading it to S3,
>   and issuing the restore task.

Trying this now...

Comment: Is the backup taken using aws export or from a local sqlserver ?

Comment: from a local non-RDS server. i have also tested restoring locally on a different server and it works fine.

Comment: Have  you gone through this  as well ?  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/SQLServer.Procedural.Importing.Snapshots.html

Comment: yes - unless i'm missing something, the options on that page are either about working with DBs that already exist on RDS or are migration options that don't copy all the code, just the data. so you don't get stored procedures and what-not.

Comment: it seems like there is an issue occasionally that involves an existing database with the same family_guid, but i've tested this on brand new instances that have never had prior DBs on them at all, so i don't see how that's possible.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Amazon SQL RDS, but does it expose the SQL Server log? It might have more info. `EXEC sys.xp_readerrorlog 0`. Maybe you ran out of space

Comment: apparently not -- `The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'xp_readerrorlog', database 'mssqlsystemresource', schema 'sys'.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay, i found a workaround, but i wouldn't actually say i found the problem.

i was creating the backup in a hosting environment using a cpanel. turns out that was running sql server 2012. i'm not sure if that matters.

while i could get it to restore locally, it wouldn't work in RDS.

so what i did was install the latest version of SQL Server 2017 on my desktop, restore to that machine, then do a shrink of the database and files.

after that, i did a new backup on my desktop and then uploaded to s3 and ran the restore commands.

this time it worked. no idea why.

there must be something weird about the remote backup process.

hope this helps someone else.